# ObservableCollection in ViewModel is not updated when a List changes in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

Let's say I have a model class `Data` and I would like to create `DataViewModel` and `DataView` for it. The data class looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        RandomData = new List<String>();
    }

    public List<String> RandomData {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create `DataViewModel` that encapsulates `RandomData` property. I need to bind to that `RandomData` property in some `ListView` and have it updated when the underlying model's `RandomData` changes.

If I do this:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    private Data _data;

    public DataViewModel(Data data)
    {
        _data = data;
        RandomData = new ObservableCollection<String>(_data.RandomData);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> RandomData {get; set;}
}
```

then I don't receive any updates. (I am aware that is just copying the list, I just use it to get the point across). If I used INotifyPropertyChanged on the `RandomData` property then I'd only receive notifications of new Lists being assigned to it. How do I check for change to the contents instead? What is the preferred way of doing this?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific example I would be tempted to change your model to use an ObservableCollection

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        RandomData = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> RandomData {get; set;}
}
```

and then expose this in your view model as a [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620.aspx).  Note that ReadOnlyObservableCollection is a wrapper over the original ObservableCollection.  The data isn't copied and change notifications from the original collection are reflected by the ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public DataViewModel(Data data)
    {
        RandomData = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String>(data.RandomData);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String> RandomData {get; private set;}
}
```

This is assuming that you want the view model RandomData to be read-only of course.

Comment: Yes, this is spot-on. Seems I have no choice but to use ObservableCollections.

Answer (score 1):

I believe to take notice of changes in an existing collection you would want to use INotifyCollectionChanged.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Implementing this interface may be a good method to use.  However I believe in the MVVM model article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx, in MSDN Josh Smith does this without even using this interface.  I know in the example he gives he adds customers to a collection with logic similar to:

```
void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
                foreach (CustomerViewModel custVM in e.NewItems)
                    custVM.PropertyChanged += this.OnCustomerViewModelPropertyChanged;

            if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
                foreach (CustomerViewModel custVM in e.OldItems)
                    custVM.PropertyChanged -= this.OnCustomerViewModelPropertyChanged;
        }
```

Comment: Is that a typo or do you mean I should change the Data's property to an ObservableCollection? Because I cannot change the model at all. To be more precise, I could change it, but isn't there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: My apologies, I did not read your question fully.  I believe the interface you want is INotifyCollectionChanged, which will let you know when a collection adds and removes data values to and from it, in addition to the properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Comment: See my updated answer, I mistook property changes for collection changes.  I know in the MSDN article Josh Smith handles the logic directly by exposing the event and accounting for it.  I know if you download the example you can see customers get added in real time to your main collection as well on a totally different view.

Comment: I accepted the second answer, but +1 both. Thank you for the effort, using the ObservableCollection seems to be the only way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (a little bit aside of MVVM but works). Add this to OnNagivatedTo of your View code-behind and it will refresh the data anytime:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();
}
```

Option 2:

```
 raise RaisePropertyChanged(YourItem);
```