# How to bind observebale collection to collections in the model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Basically this is a very very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530770/observablecollection-in-viewmodel-is-not-updated-when-a-list-changes-in-model), with the big difference that I cannot easily "just use an observable collection inside the model"; a good example is the keycollection of a dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Data
{
    private Dictionary<String, String> _randomData;
    public Data()
    {
        _randomData = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    }

    public ICollection<string> RandomDataKeys {
        get {
            return _randomData.Keys;
        }
    }

    public void AddElement(string k, string v) {
        _randomData[k] = v;
    }
}


public class DataViewModel
{
    private Data _data;

    public DataViewModel(Data data)
    {
        _data = data;
        RandomData = new ObservableCollection<String>(_data.RandomDataKeys);
        //obviously above wouldn't work, since it just copies the keys.
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> RandomData {get; set;}
}
```

Now what is the common approach here? A backup is to change the "add" function to tell the viewmodel that a new item is added (but that would require the model to have information about the viewmodel, explicitly calling a function on the viewmodel to tell the viewmodel to keep a duplicate of the model's data, this feels wasteful and slow).

Comment: Raise an event in your model and subscribe to it in your view model, when you add an item.

Comment: It all depends on what the real code actually looks like, so the question is too broad. The only commonality will be that you will need some mechanism for being notified when the underlying data changes. Obviously this doesn't happen automatically for the dictionary or its related collections themselves; you'll need to first own the code that does any modifications, and then change _that_ code to delivery appropriate notifications. Having done that, you can then either expose the data and notifications directly to WPF, or mediate through e.g. `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that when you're doing this `RandomData = new ObservableCollection<String>(_data.RandomDataKeys);` , you basically create a new instance of collection. So when you update your `_data.RandomDataKeys`, this changed are not reflected in your observable collection.
Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx), please
The best way would be to use ObservableCollection in your Data class, but if you don't want to do so, you can change your

```
public ObservableCollection<String> RandomData {get; set;}
```

To

```
public ObservableCollection<String> RandomData 
{    
    get { return new ObservableCollection(_data.RandomDataKeys); }
}
```

**But** that is definately **not a good idea**, to create each time new collection.
So you can try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your Data class and bind directly to your `_data.RandomDataKeys`

Comment: I might be overthinking things here: but is the core behind the mv(c)vm paradigm not that the model is basically just a data-containing class. With as little logic as possible? - Stretching from that, shouldn't it be a complete blackbox and not having to update if the requirements for the view change?

Comment: @paul23, well, I'd said that the mvvm does not dictate you to actually do something, It's just common pattern of solution design. And you shouldn't strictly follow mvvm ONLY TO follow mvvm. Model is some kind of abstract thing, it easily can be data classes(DTO/Business/Data entities) as well as business logic of your project. And model, if it is data, must always contain a notifying event, that fires when data changes and VM can detect that(model doesn't even know that it's event is being used in VM). Look at [this](http://cases.azoft.com/mvvm-android-data-binding/) scheme, please

Comment: @paul23 I'm asp.net mvc programmer, and not so experienced in WPF/MVVM, but when I used to, I simply create some sort of BaseNotifyingModel, which implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface and used classes, inherited from that base class inside of Window/Page/Componen's VM. And I don't see any necessity to create a separate VM class for any data entity/DTO/etc that is stored in "Model" as long as I don't need to create big VM class.